# How to get latest file from sftp server to local using mget in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Hi I am following below logic to get the latest file from sftp server. But it is copying all the files. Please help what I need to correct in my logic?

```
datadir="********"
cd ${datadir}
rm -f ${datadir}/my_data*.csv
rm -f ${logfile}
lftp<<END_SCRIPT
open sftp://${sftphost}
user ${sftpuser} ${sftppassword}
cd ${sftpfolder}
lcd $datadir
mget my_data*csv | sed 's/-\([1-9]\)\./-0\1\./g' | sort -r | sed 's/-0\([1-9]\)\./-\1\./g' | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code, `mget my_data*csv` will execute first, and its output will be provided to `sed` as a parameter:

```sh
mget my_data*csv | sed 's/-\([1-9]\)\./-0\1\./g' | sort -r | sed 's/-0\([1-9]\)\./-\1\./g' | head -1
```

You just need to get the filename you want first and then do the `mget filename`.

Comment: Ohkk... Can u pls tell me the change what I need to do?

Comment: dont have a ftp now,guess `mget $(ls my_data*csv | sed 's/-\([1-9]\)\./-0\1\./g' | sort -r | sed 's/-0\([1-9]\)\./-\1\./g' | head -1)`

Comment: not giving output